# J.c higgins bike

Tags: repair

[image]I also have the.model #, 50545120 and serial #
0408039.
I would like to find out any info please.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  What kind of info do you want?  Do you want to know where to get parts?  How to maintain it?  Please make your question as specific as possible.

Comment: If you're after general information about the brand, google returns useful results like http://www.american-vintage-bicycles.com/home/bicycle-manufacturers/j-c-higgins-bicycle/    Serial numbers are not VINs and are not helpful, sorry.   If you have a problem on this bike then ask specifically.